# Python 3: Variable Scoping

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, scoping

```
def max_sum_subarray(arr):
    cur_max_sum = global_max_sum = arr[0]
    start = end = 0

    sz = len(arr)
    for i in range(1, sz):
        cur_max_sum = max(arr[i], cur_max_sum+arr[i])
        global_max_sum = max(global_max_sum, cur_max_sum)
        if cur_max_sum > global_max_sum:
            global_max_sum = cur_max_sum
            end = i
    g = global_max_sum

    for i in range(end, -1, -1):
        g -= arr[i]
        if not g:
            start = i
            break

    ans = {
        'global_max_sum': global_max_sum,
        'start': start+1,
        'end': end+1
    }
    return ans
```

Here, `start` and `end` don't get updated inside for loop under `if`, though the condition satisfies.
If `start` or `end` is used out of `if`, there is no problem with it. Is there any scoping problem or something else? Please explain me in details.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Following [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) helps you find this kind of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a logic error:

```
global_max_sum = max(global_max_sum, cur_max_sum)
if cur_max_sum > global_max_sum:
```

There's literally no way for `cur_max_sum` to be greater than `global_max_sum`.

Comment: I've transformed `global_max_sum = max(global_max_sum, cur_max_sum)` into `if` , but forgot to comment it. Thanks @Mr. Llama.